# Use of SELECT INTO

Tags: mysql

Is it necessary to define the new table definition before using `SELECT INTO` query in MYSQL.

I am getting problem to execute the query when I writ e like:

```
SELECT *
INTO newtable
FROM oldtable
WHERE 1=0;
```

the error showing is:

> Undeclared variabie: newtable

Answer (score 2):

### if you have newtable

try :

```
INSERT INTO newtable SELECT ...
```

### if you don't have newtable

try :

```
CREATE TABLE newtable AS SELECT ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL manual search engine is terrible but googling for something like `mysql 5.5 select into` will normally take you to [the right page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ansi-diff-select-into-table.html):

> MySQL Server doesn't support the SELECT ... INTO TABLE Sybase SQL
>   extension. Instead, MySQL Server supports the INSERT INTO ... SELECT
>   standard SQL syntax, which is basically the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you [read the documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) it says:

`With INSERT ... SELECT, you can quickly insert many rows into a table from one or many tables`

So, yes, you need to create the new table first.

You can use `CREATE TABLE new LIKE old` to create a new, empty table, which is a copy of the original table structure.